# How to do type hinting for a template parameter in pycharm3?

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I noticed that when I use the function render or render_to_reponse in a django view, I can auto complete and referenced the template in the template string.

When I tried to do the same for my method the string does not response the same way even though I named the parameter template_name same as the "render" method.

```
def my_render(self, template_name):
    """
    My custom render method
    :type template_name: Template|str
    """
    return render(self.request, template_name, self.context)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those code insight features are attached to specific full-qualified function names from the Django implementation. It's unfortunately not currently possible to enable those features for a function in your own project.